# Set environment variables from external file in serverless.yml

Tags: environment-variables, yaml, serverless-framework

I'm using serverless and serverless-local for local development.

I've got an external file which holds references to environment variables which I retrieve from `node.env` in my app.

From what I understand, I should be able to set my environment variables such as

```
dev:
   AWS_KEY: 'key',
   SECRET: 'secret
test:
   AWS_KEY: 'test-key',
   SECRET: 'test-secret',
etc:
   ...
```

and have those environment variables included in my app through the following line in my serverless.yml

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs4.3
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:custom.default_stage}
  deploymentBucket: serverless-deploy-packages/${opt:stage, self:custom.default_stage}
  environment: 
    ${file(./serverless-env.yml):${opt:stage, self:custom.default_stage}}
```

then in the commandline, I call

`serverless offline --stage dev --port 9000`

I thought this would include the correct vars in my app, but it isn't working. Is this not how it is supposed to work? Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 9):

From [docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#reference-variables-in-other-files):

You can set the contents of an external file into a variable:

```
file: ${file(./serverless-env.yml)}
```

And later you can use this new variable to access the file variables.

```
secret: file.dev.SECRET
```

Or you can use the file directly:

```
secret: ${file(./serverless-env.yml):dev.SECRET}
```

Comment: The docs are incomplete, and though it 'can' be done as you describe that is more verbose than needed. Passing values directly to the environment entry in yaml does work, I just had an error in where the file was pointing, which apparently doesn't cause an error in yaml.

Answer (score 9):

You can also now use remote async values with the serverless framework. See https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-v1.13.0/

This means you can call values from s3 or remote databases etc.

Example:

**serverless.yml**

```
service: serverless-async-vars

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10

custom:
  secret: ${file(./vars.js):fetchSecret} # JS file running async / promised
```

**vars.js**

```js
module.exports.fetchSecret = () => {
  // async code
  return Promise.resolve('SomeSecretKey');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is how you can separate your environments by different stages:

`serverless.yml`:

```
custom:
  test:
    project: xxx
  prod:
    project: yyy

provider:
  ...
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'test'}
  project: ${self:custom.${opt:stage, 'test'}.project}
  environment:
    ${file(.env.${opt:stage, 'test'}.yml):}

package:
  exclude:
    - .env.*
```

`.env.test.yml`:

```
VARIABLE1: value1
VARIABLE2: value2
```

During deploy, pass `--stage=prod` or skip and `test` project will be deployed. Then in your JS code you can access ENV variables with `process.env.VARIABLE1`.

Comment: also you could replace `${self:custom.${opt:stage, 'test'}.project}` with `${self:custom.${self:provider.stage}.project}`

Answer (score 1):

Set Lambda environment variables from JSON file ( using AWS CLI)

aws lambda update-function-configuration --profile mfa --function-name test-api --cli-input-json file://dev.json

Answer (score 0):

I had this correct, but I was referencing the file incorrectly.

I don't see this in the docs, but passing a file to `environment` will include the files yaml file, and the above structure does work.

Comment: I tried your approach and it works. but the problem I am getting an error like this `Cannot create property 'PORT' on string '${file....etc file path`
any idea?